# Reviewers decision: Summary rejects typically do not receive technical feedback

Tags: conference

I would like to know what does this imply "Summary rejects typically do not receive technical feedback". Is that mean that work has a flaw?

Answer (score 4):

"Summary" here is used in the sense of "performed speedily and without formal ceremony" (see [Wiktionary, adjective definition 2](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/summary)).

They have concluded that the paper is clearly not suitable for publication in this journal / conference, and so they are rejecting it without a full review.  In such a case you will not receive detailed technical feedback about the work.

Some possible reasons:

- The work is on a topic not covered by the conference
- The importance or interest of the result is much less than what the conference normally expects
- The work has major obvious technical flaws
- The paper is extremely poorly written or incomprehensible
- Your paper doesn't conform to the conference's submission requirements  (e.g. formatting, page count, double-blinding)

It would be wise to have a colleague in your field look at the paper before trying to resubmit somewhere else.

Comment: I dont think so it has a technical flaw, they have mentioned that the number of pages is extra than the allowed. It is a reputed conference, and I wished to publish, however I did that on my own without any help.

Comment: Okay, then that could be the reason.  They simply rejected it for having too many pages. Probably nobody ever read the contents at all, so you cannot expect to get any technical feedback.

Comment: Actually, I am quite anxious and having mixed feelings the part of this work has been accepted at workshops where it had been held at reputed conferences. Now the question is: should I submit to another conference or give up, as the reviewer said there are many reasons and one of them number of the pages, but I have the feeling that they didnot read the paper. Honestly, I become to feel disappointed because I dont have full paper at reputed conference and journal, and I dont know whether this could be a red flag not to continue in research.

Comment: Seems like the main thing you should learn from this is to follow the directions

Comment: @Monika: As explained above, your paper wasn't read because it did not follow the prescribed page limit. So the rejection doesn't imply that anyone thought your research is bad. You shouldn't feel discouraged, but you should learn to follow the guidelines such as page limits.

Comment: @Monika: They didn't give you feedback, and so you simply can't tell from this rejection whether the work has potential for publication or not.  I do not see any reason to give up based on this alone.  If it's been accepted at previous workshops, that seems like good reason to think that it has promise.  If you want feedback (and it's probably a good idea), you will have to show it to someone else.  You're more likely to get timely and thorough feedback from someone you know, rather than depending on anonymous peer review.

Comment: @Monika: So to summarize: (1) Don't give up.  (2) Seek feedback from someone you know, who knows the field.  (3) Think carefully about the feedback you get from them, and any other feedback you may have received.  (4) Revise the paper accordingly.  (5) Submit somewhere else.